# Extracting tokens from a document: applying Deep Learning or Classification?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, nlp

I have a legal document from Law. That document is 4-pages of evidence from the plaintiff. I want to identify the Dates, Addresses and Financial transactions in that document.

Can I apply deep learning, the data with me is very small, on just one 4-page document, or should I apply Text Classification to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to find certain things in text can be done quite easily if you have the real text, and not a scanned document that is a PDF or even an image. This is actually quite a big topic and can become quite difficult.

### Pure text

If you have pure text, you can parse out parts you need using custom regular expressions, e.g. to find a date, you might use this:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

> matches a date in yyyy-mm-dd format from 1900-01-01 through 2099-12-31, with a choice of four separators ([source](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)).

I believe there are even a few libraries that specifically find dates for you within text.

### PDF

There are actually many types of PDF, i.e. there are many ways a pdf can be encoded behind the scenes. Some types are easier to parse that others, but luckily there are libraries that can help with that. For example, check out [PDFMiner](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer).

After using such a library, you will hopefully be left with the pure text, and can maybe go back to using methods from that section.

### Images

If you are unlucky enough to have an image as a starting point, then you are now in the realms of OCR - **Optical Character Recognition**. I would recommend reading [**this blog post**](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-ocr-ee1469a201aa) for a more complete description of possible methods,but in a nutshell, you can try using either:

1. a traditional algorithm from compute vision (applying filters and looking for edges etc.)
2. a trained model specialised for text (e.g. [**EAST: an Efficient and Accurate Scene Text Detector**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03155))
3. a general model

A nice model to help out with OCR is [**the Tesseract library**](https://stackabuse.com/pytesseract-simple-python-optical-character-recognition/).

---

You said you are learning NLP, so actually extracting tokens from a PDF might not be the best example with which to start. I would recommend first deciding exactly what you really want to learn and follow a course or a tutorial on that topic.area.

Comment: thankyou for the answer. I have a .txt file which is unstructured.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, it might be easier to use text classification or regular expressions.